# TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc svd_n_s

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

i'm trying to apply Extreme Machine Learning code on my dataset ... i get this erorr

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc svd_n_s

this is my code:

```
X = d[:,0:208]
y = d[:,208]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
input_size = X_train.shape[1]
hidden_size = 1000
input_weights = np.random.normal(size=[input_size,hidden_size])
biases = np.random.normal(size=[hidden_size])
output_weights =  float(np.matmul(np.linalg.pinv(hidden_nodes(X_train)), y_train))


prediction = predict(X_test)
correct = 0
total = X_test.shape[0]
for i in range(total):
   predicted = np.argmax(prediction[i])
   actual = np.argmax(y_test[i])
   correct += 1 if predicted == actual else 0
accuracy = correct/total
print('Accuracy for ', hidden_size, ' hidden nodes: ', accuracy)
```

any help please?????????